# Auto-Update a MySQL row exactly after n seconds after the insert

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

I have this table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `comp` (
  `id_comp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_exam` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_stop` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=open, 0=closed, -1=forced',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_comp`)
);
```

In another table (exam) I have the max_execution_time allowed, e.g. 600 seconds.
After 600 seconds, if I have the status already open (1) I would update the row, change the status to -1 and fill the data_stop field (with CURRENT_DATETIME).

I already realized this with an external script (resque).
Should I do with the DB itself, maybe with a stored procedure? It's possible with MySQL?

I tried with a stored procedure and a `SLEEP()`, but it blocks the execution (and the asynch execution seems not feasible). On other hand the `EVENT` syntax cannot accept parameters.

Any idea?

Thanks

p.s. Otherwise, can I do it with Postgresql?

Comment: Inserting the row you may [create event procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) which will perform this action. Or you may create permanent procedure which executes each second and perform the action over those rows if they exists.

Comment: From the other side - does this makes sense? You may check the same during retrieve and return "forced" status if more than 10 minutes elapsed, and check during any update and alter status if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the data to "look" correct, then you can use a view.  The view can calculate the statuses on-the-fly:

```
create view v_comp as
    select c.id_comp, c.id_exam, c.date_start,
           (case when date_end is not null then date_end
                 when now() > c.date_start + interval e.max_execution_time second
                 then c.date_start + interval e.max_execution_time second
            end) as date_end,
           (case when date_end is not null then status
                 when now() > c.date_start + interval e.max_execution_time second
                 then -1
            end) as status
    from comp c join
         exams e
         on c.id_exam = e.id_exam;
```

The advantage of this approach is that the data *always* is correct.  There is no problem with delays on the computer delaying things by a second or two -- or perhaps much longer.

You can actually update the data in a variety of ways:

- A batch process, such as once per day or once per hour for rows that need to be updated.
- You could use a queueing system, where the `update` is inserted into the queue.  In MySQL, this would probably use the event scheduler.